# Makes a file named with current date d:m:Y

Tags: php, ubuntu, filenames

PHP

```
$file = fopen((string)date("d-m-Y").".php","w");
fwrite($file,'Body');
fclose($file);
```

Makes a file named `22-11-2015` correctly .

But

```
$file = fopen((string)date("d:m:Y").".php","w");
fwrite($file,'Body');
fclose($file);
```

Makes a file named `23P826~3`!!!!.

Why can not set `:` for file name in Ubuntu?

Comment: Colon is a [reserved character](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#file_and_directory_names) for file names on windows.

Comment: `php -r 'file_put_contents("test-".date("d:m:Y"), "");'` works fine on Debian. And what's with the `(string)`? Ow, and if you use `date("Y-m-d")` you can sort by date ;-)

Comment: Your script also works fine. What filesystem are you using? I'm on ext4; PHP version 5.6.13, $LANG en_US.utf-8.

Comment: I use samba and php 5.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a start you can check [Wikipedia Filename page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename) for further information.

From my point of view, special characters should be avoided in file and directory names to avoid unnecessary stress...